# Connecting html in different packages in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm new to Django development and have come across a problem with my web pages.
From My understanding, each separate function should be written in different packages, such that html would have it's own set of models, views and urls.

My question is how to connect these pages in such a way that I could link between them when displaying my html pages on a web browser.

I have read the official Django documentation, but I am still having trouble understanding, specifically with what goes in the urls.py (There's an example strip of code, but doesn't really explain what each part of the code is). And also what I need in my views.py.

I am working in Eclipse IDE, with python34 and Django 1.6.

Comment: It is not like every function should be written i separate package. The heart of djnago project is settings.py file. initially specify correct settings for each attribute in it. (e.g to connect to your html files give html file path in TEMPLETE_DIR attribute in settings.py file)

Comment: What exactly is missing from the [exceedingly comprehensive documentation on urls.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/)?

Comment: Daniel's question is exactly why SO regulars frequently ask "what did you try?" when a question is posted without indicating what was tried. It is unclear what it is *exactly* you do not understand from the documentation if you do not show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I can best explain how the whole process works in simple terms.

Take an example of a website, www.xyz.com,that sells mobile phones online.Lets say that this website has got just 3 pages. The first is home page,second is a listings page,where all mobile phones are listed and third is the product page, where you get all the information about a mobile phone.

Now,lets say the home page is available on the url www.xyz.com/home/ ,the lisitng page is available on www.xyz.com/mobile-lisitng/ and the individual product page is available on www.xyz.com/apple-5s or samsung-s5 or whatever the slug of the product is.Your urls.py file will look something like this :

urls.py

```
url(r'^/home/$', 'web.views.home'),
url(r'^/mobile-listing/$', 'web.views.listing'),
url(r'^/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'web.views.product_page'),
```

So now,whenever a request comes on the URL www.xyz.com/home/ , the 'home' function in your views.py file will be called.The home function then takes care of rendering the html page of home.
Similarly, when a request comes on .../mobile-listing/ or ..../{any_slug}/, then the control will be given over to listing and product_page functions,respectively.

So, lets say your home page has a link to listing page.So in the home.html file you can have a line of code like this

```
<a href="/mobile-listing/"> See all mobile phones </a>
```

and maybe a link to a specific product page

```
<a href="/{{mobile_slug}}/"> (Name of the phone)</a>
```

So now this will be the flow.

1) User clicks on any of the above links from the home page.

2) The urls.py file is checked to see which URL pattern matches and if the match is found, then go to the specified function.

3) In the function you there is business logic and the the requested page is rendered.

Thats it. This is how you link the pages.Just give the right url links and make sure that the matching url is present in urls.py and the function is written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `urls.py` to define URL addresses for your views.

Then, use the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) function if you want to link to a particular view ("page") from within another view; or the [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag to create a link from within a template.